# How to display aggregated and non-aggregated values at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas

I've gout an hourly time series over the strecth of a year. I'd like to display daily, and/or monthly aggregated values along with the source data in a plot. The most solid way would supposedly be to add those aggregated values to the source dataframe and take it from there. I know how to take an hourly series like this:

[image]

And show hour by day for the whole year like this:

[image]

But what I'm looking for is to display the whole thing like below, where the aggregated data are shown togehter with the source data. Mock example:

[image]

And I'd like to do it for various time aggregations like day, week, month, quarter and year.

I know this question is a bit broad, but I've been banging my head against this problem for longer than I'd like to admit. Thank you for any suggestions!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

time = pd.date_range(start='01.01.2020', end='31.12.2020', freq='1H')
A = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=len(time)).tolist()

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'time':time, 'A':np.cumsum(A)})
df1.set_index('time', inplace=True)
df1.plot()


times = pd.DatetimeIndex(df1.index)
df2 = df1.groupby([times.month, times.day]).mean()

df2.plot()
```

**Code sample:**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `step` function, and also, a different way to groupby:

```
# replace '7D' with '1D' to match your code
# but 1 day might be too small to see the steps
df2 = df1.groupby(df1.index.floor('7D')).mean()

plt.step(df2.index, df2.A, c='r')
plt.plot(df1.index, df1.A)
```

Output:

[image]